# MySQL looping "insert into"

Tags: java, mysql

saveProfit method

```
public void saveProfit() throws SQLException {
    ObservableList<Bread> bread = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bakery", "root", "a3756421");
        statement = conn.createStatement();
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM bread");
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            Bread newBread = new Bread(
            resultSet.getString("breadName"),
            resultSet.getString("breadType"),
            resultSet.getString("breadFlavour"),
            resultSet.getInt("breadStock"),
            resultSet.getInt("breadPrice"));
            newBread.setBreadId(resultSet.getInt("breadId"));
            bread.add(newBread);
        }

        for(Bread b : bread){
            String sql = "insert into best5(pname, profit) values (?,?)";
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1,b.getBreadName());
            ps.setInt(2, b.getBreadPrice()*b.getBreadStock());
        }

        for(Bread b : bread){
            String sql = "insert into worst5(pname, profit) values (?,?)";
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1,b.getBreadName());
            ps.setInt(2, b.getBreadPrice()*b.getBreadStock());
        }
    }
}
```

Bread object

public class Bread {

```
private String breadName, breadFlavour, breadType;
private int breadStock, breadPrice, breadId;
private File imageFile;
private Image photo;

public Bread(String breadName, String breadType, String breadFlavour,int breadPrice, int breadStock) {
    setBreadName(breadName);
    setBreadType(breadType);
    setBreadFlavour(breadFlavour);
    setBreadPrice(breadPrice);
    setBreadStock(breadStock);
    setImageFile(new File("./src/Images/foodDefault.png"));

}
```

bread table

```
create table bread (
    breadId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    breadName VARCHAR(30),
    breadType VARCHAR(30),
    breadFlavour VARCHAR(30),
    breadStock INT,
    breadPrice DOUBLE,
    imageFile VARCHAR(100));
```

best5 table

```
create table best5 (
    id INT not null primary key auto_increment,
    pname VARCHAR(30),
    profit INT);
```

worst5 table is basically the same with different name.

So, I am trying to loop the `insert into best5(pname, profit) values(?,?)` to store data from bread table. But, it seems like only the first row of bread table is stored into best5 table and the rest is ignored. What am I doing wrong? I am new to javafx and MySQL. Please correct my mistakes.

Comment: how is this related to fx (except having a ObservableList)?

Comment: I thought I had to include it as long as it had a feature of javafx

Comment: don't think so: use a plain list until you solved the sql problem, then go ahead with a observableList in a ui. If it turns out that there is a part related to observable/ui, post a new question with the fx tag (and a [mcve] demonstrating what goes wrong :)

Comment: Note that it's rare for anything called 'price' to be anything other than DECIMAL. And it's rare to want to store derived data